# Y axis not long enough (Log scale)

Tags: r, logging, scale

Hi,
I'm trying to get a visually pleasing Y axis

```
counts=c(Low = 3553, Mid = 203, High = 3158, Low = 13, Mid = NA, High = NA,Low = 16, Mid = 14, High = NA,Low = 1, Mid = 7, High = 21)
barplot(counts,log="y",ylab="Total counts from quadrats (Log scale)",axes=F)
axis(2, 0:4000)
```

[image]
As you can tell from the results, things get a bit messy. And if I do axes=T, the axis just stops at 1000.

Comment: I think it is not clear how can we help you... What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify where you want the tick marks in `axis`. Also, change the `ylim` in `barplot` appropriately.

```
   counts=c(Low = 3553, Mid = 203, High = 3158, Low = 13, Mid = NA, 
        High = NA,Low = 16, Mid = 14, High = NA,Low = 1, Mid = 7, High = 21)

    barplot(counts,log="y",
            ylab="Total counts from quadrats (Log scale)",
            axes=F,
            ylim = c(1, 4096))

    axis(2, c(1, 8, 124, 4096))
```

[image]